# Correctly closing multiple hop SSH tunnel

Tags: ssh, rhel, ssh-tunneling

I want to tunnel VNC traffic to `host2`, which is only accessible from `host1`, whereas `host1` is publicly accessible.

I setup a multi-hop SSH tunnel as described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/96489/ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops), using:

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:6000 host1 ssh -L 6000:localhost:5901 -N host2
```

This indeed works perfectly and does the job. However, I don't know how to correctly close the nested tunnel. I tried **Ctrl+c** but this seems to kill the first `ssh` instance to `host1`. But, the second `ssh` tunnel between `host1` and `host2` remains open, which is highly undesirable as any one can actually forward traffic through it.

Also, with `-N` option, I don't get an actual `tty` on `host2`, so I can't simply `exit` from there.
Without, `-N`, I still don't get a `tty`, instead I get the following error:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.
term: Undefined variable.
```

I am starting the connection from MacOS X, and both host1 and host2 are running RHEL 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with tty, and the `-t` option gives you just that. However, unless you are actually aiming to get a tty session for interacting, leave this option off of the last ssh command in your chain. In your case you just need it on the first connection:

`ssh -L 5901:localhost:6000 host1 -t ssh -L 6000:localhost:5901 -N host2`

Now when you use **Ctrl-C**, the tunnel will between all hosts.